# Request an Access Token Using Client Secret Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I have 2 API's: A and B. Both are registred in Azure AD as a API. In azure i generated a KEY to B.

Now i need generate a Access Token so i'm using ADAL Library to Java. I'm trying to use this method:

```
public Future<AuthenticationResult> acquireToken(final String resource,
            final UserAssertion userAssertion, final ClientCredential credential,
            final AuthenticationCallback callback)
```

I have the ClientCredital information but i don't have userAsstion and i don't know how generate it. Someone can help ?

This is my call:

```
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("http://localhost:8081",SHOULD_BE_ASSERTION,
                    new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID,SECRET),null);
```

Comment: Do you want to call the API as a user or as the API itself? For example, if API A is called by a client with delegated permissions, then API A can use on-behalf-of to get another user token for B. If not, then you need to use another overload of acquireToken to get the token with client credentials.

Comment: I want to call API as a API not user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what exactly OAuth flow are you trying to achieve.

The easiest in your case, and from the context of your question is `Client Credentials` flow ([described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service)) without user interaction. For that flow, you need one particular overload of the [`AcquireToken method`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j/1.6.0/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationContext.html#acquireToken-java.lang.String-com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential-com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationCallback-), namley:

```
Future<AuthenticationResult>    acquireToken(String resource, ClientCredential credential, AuthenticationCallback callback)
```

In that overload you only supply the [`ClientCredentials`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j/1.6.0/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/ClientCredential.html) which is composed of the client_id and client_secret.

The `UserAssertion` is required for a different OAuth flow - `on-behalf-of` (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of)). And this is only possible when you have end user context. This would be the Access Token for Web Api A.

Please take your time to go through the documentation and understand the different flows. Then you will also understand the libraries and SDKs.

Comment: I tried using your method acquireToken without USerAssertion but i got : "error_description":"AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials

Comment: well, then you have to carefully read the docs and configure your [AuthenticationContext](http://static.javadoc.io/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j/1.6.0/index.html?com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationContext.html) as well as your applications in Azure AD. And the `resource` parameter shall be the App ID URI of your Api B.

Comment: Yeah, and from comments it is indeed client credentials flow which you need :)

Comment: So, i got the Access Token using your method but now i need transfer this token thought REST to API A, this API A need validate this token. Any suggestion ?

Comment: The only API that should validate an `access_token` is the API that the token is issued for! If you have access token for API B, then only B shall validate the token.  All other parties (like API A) shall look at the `access token` as just a string. Beside, this is another question. Would you be so kind to accept the answer as it obviously brought you the solution you were asking for.

Comment: for more complex sample, check [this repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/master/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter/README.md) it includes Web API written in Spring Boot and protected by bearer access token.